# Use of "guarantee" in "What is the guarantee that..."

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, nouns

> A: Are you going to invest in that plan?
>   B: I dont think so, it seems confusing and vague to me. What is the guarantee that my money will not be lost?

Is *guarantee* okay here? If not, what other word can I use?

Comment: *Guarantee* is fine (Did you look it up? What did you find which indicated it's not ok?) But you have an extra *is* in Guy2's question which is not fine at all.

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww#q=%22What+is+the+guarantee+that%22&hl=en&tbo=d&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=Vdr_UKu9J42NrgeVh4DgDQ&ved=0CAwQ_AUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.bmk&fp=7c827136919f8ba0&biw=1024&bih=604

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22What+is+the+guarantee+that%22&oq=%22What+is+the+guarantee+that%22&gs_l=hp.3...1560689.1565590.0.1566245.4.4.0.0.0.0.178.457.2j2.4.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.YpfZF2sUMlw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.bmk&fp=51e620f240bb9f76&biw=1024&bih=604

Comment: You don't seem to have checked precedence.

Comment: I might also say _What **guarantees** that my money will not be lost?_ But there's nothing wrong with your sentence.

Answer (score 2):

It is, but a native speaker might say *What guarantee is there that my money will not be lost?*

Comment: It's hard to say why, but I'd definitely prefer your rephrasing over OP's original. Perhaps it's to do with the fact that for most purposes, there either is or isn't a guarantee. So you don't normally ask *what exactly is it?* - you ask *whether it exists*.